# Flutter Integration test in TestLab for iOS - Use cases are not divided in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-test, firebase-test-lab

I'm using test lab in Firebase and the issue I'm finding is with the results in iOS because it is not showing all the use cases in my integration test.

This is my result in Android I can see all the use cases in TestLab.

[image: Results of Android in TestLab]

In iOS I cannot find my test cases and I only find one use cases that calls my two use cases.

[image: Results of iOS in TestLab]

I have checked the logs and the two test cases is executed in iOS, but the problem is with result showed in the TestLab Console. I would like to see all the use cases.

Comment: Hi there. Have you found a solution for this? I'm also facing the same issue and can't find any documented solution out there.

Comment: I could not find a solution to display the test cases. The only way to see the different use cases is to search in the logs. Would be nice to see the result like in Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/95704, Flutter `integration_test` will dynamically create a native XCTestCase per dart test. This will match Android's behavior, and you should see 1:1 test results in TestLab, or if you run your tests locally in Xcode from `ios/Runner.xcworkspace`.

The fix will be available in the next stable release.